# How to write clear and maintainable code when dealing with tables?

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet, listobject

In my projects I often take advantage of tables and underlying ListObjects and ListColumns. I like them as they're easier to reference and update than bare Range objects. Yet I still haven't found a sane and maintainable way to handle multiple ListObjects consisting of many ListColumns and being referenced across all Worksheets in a project.

Let's say I have Worksheet (with (Name) property set to "WorksheetA") that contains table (called TableA) with few columns (called Column1, Column2, ..., Column10).

Now I want to reference one of the columns from the code of another Worksheet. I could do it as follows:

```
WorksheetA.ListObjects("TableA").ListColumns("Column7")
```

Now, it's a bad practice to use string directly, as it's difficult to maintain and prone to errors.

So what now?

I could create dedicated module to store my string as constants. For example, module called "Constants":

```
Public Const TABLE_A As String = "TableA"
Public Const COLUMN7 As String = "Column7"
```

Then my reference could be converted to:

```
WorksheetA.ListObjects(Constants.TABLE_A).ListColumns(Constants.COLUMN7)
```

However, this solution has some disadvantages:

1. Constants module would grow ridiculously fast with each table and column added.
2. Reference itself grows and becomes less readable.
3. All constants related to tables from across all workbooks are thrown into one giant pit.

I could store constants inside WorksheetA, and make them available through Public Functions like:

```
Private Const TABLE_A As String = "TableA"
Private Const COLUMN7 As String = "Column7"

Public Function GetTableAName() As String
    GetTableAName = TABLE_A
End Function

Public Function GetTableA() As ListObject
    Set GetTableA = WorksheetA.ListObjects(TABLE_A)
End Function

Public Function GetTableAColumn7() As ListColumn
    Set GetTableAColumn7 = GetTableA().ListColumns(COLUMN7)
End Function
```

This solution actually solves all three problems mentioned above, yet it's still a bit "dirty" and time-consuming, as adding a new table introduces a requirement to create a function for each column.

Do you have better idea how to deal with this problem?

**EDIT1 (for clarity):** Let's assume that user must not change any names (neither table names nor column names). If user does so, it is he/she to blame.

**EDIT2 (for clarity):** I've used Column7 as column name only as an example. Let's assume that columns have more meaningful names.

Comment: Interesting problem. If there was a simple solution for this, I guess we would have seen it applied in Data Access libraries such as DAO, ADO, JDBC etc. The only thing that developers can do to encapsulate these "field names" and "table names" is to write "persistent" classes, i.e. one class for each table or data object. That is the "clean" solution but it adds a layer and is time consuming. It is recommended for big DB projects, but I doubt that an Excel project would reach such a scale that this solution becomes really necessary.

Comment: I guess you are worried that in the string approach, the table names can be changed by user hence breaking the reference. If you have only one table on the worksheet, you can use index number (1) instead of string. This is only valid for max one table per sheet. Dont know, if that is applicable accross all your sheets. It would in your example.

Comment: If your column names are really as nondescript as `Column7` then why not reference them by numerical index?

Comment: I am a big proponent of constants, but I think your idea takes it too far. I wouldn't bother with this at all. You are making much work for no benefit. It does not stop the user from changing the names of the tables or the columns. And then it comes down to what you want to do with the columns. I primarily work with arrays in VBA. So instead of dealing with all of the quotation marks and object references, you can get all of the values of the column from structured references in to an array like so:  `v = [Table1[Column7]]`

Comment: You could also make a generic ListColumn returning function. Pass it the ws name, table name, and column name, and it returns the ListColumn object. I would not define the names of these things anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my two cents. I'm not an educated programmer, but I do get paid to do it, so I guess it makes me professional.

The first line of defense is that I create a class to model a table. I fill the class from the table and no other code even knows where the data lives. When I initialize, I'll run code like

```
clsEmployees.FillFromListObject wshEmployees.ListObjects(1)
```

Then in the class, the code looks like

```
vaData = lo.DataBodyRange.Value
...
clsEmployee.EeName = vaData(i,1)
clsEmployee.Ssn = vaData(i,2) 
etc
```

Only one ListObject per worksheet. That's my rule and I never break it. Anyone with access to the worksheet could rearrange the columns and break my code. If I want to use Excel as a database, and sometimes I do, then that is the risk I take. If it's so critical that I can't take that risk, then I store my data in SQL Server, SQLite, or JET.

Instead of putting the range in an array, I could actually call out the ListColumns names. That way if someone rearranged the columns, my code will still work. But it introduces that they could rename the columns, so I'm just trading one risk for another. It would make the code more readable, so it may be the trade you want to make. I like the speed of filling from an array, so that's the trade I make.

If my project is sufficiently small or is supposed to work directly with ListObjects, then I follow the same rules as I do for any Strings.

- I use Strings in code exactly once.
- If I uses it more than once, I make a procedure-level constant
- If I use it in more than one procedure, I try to pass it as an argument
- If I can't pass it as an argument, I make a module-level constant
- If the two procedures are in different modules, I first ask myself why two procedures are in different modules that use the same constant. Shouldn't related procedures be in the same module?
- If the two procedures really belong in the different modules, then I try to pass it as an argument
- If none of that works, then it truly is a global constant and I set up in my MGlobals module.

If MGlobals takes up more than about half a screen, I'm doing something wrong and I need to step back and think through what I'm trying to accomplish. And then I make a custom class.